# windows batch script to unzip a file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that gets a zipped folder for that particular date (v_date) from the sftp site and then unzip them. The zip file contains five files that are text documents. I have written batch scripts that successfully get the zip file from the remote site and save a copy of it on the local drive. I need to incorporate the unzip part in to my script.

```
SET v_date=%1
if [%v_date%] == [] SET v_date=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
echo option batch continue>FTP_File_Get.txt
echo option confirm off>>FTP_File_Get.txt
echo open Target>>FTP_File_Get.txt
echo lcd "M:\Development\Data History\File" >> FTP_File_Get.txt
echo cd /Export/File >> FTP_File_Get.txt
echo get /Export/File/Filename_%v_date%.zip "M:\Development\DataHistory\Filename_%v_date%.zip">>FTP_File_Get.txt
echo exit>>FTP_File_Get.txt
M:\temp\apps\WinSCP\winscp.com/script="M:\Development\SFTPBatchFiles\FTP_File_Get.txt"
del FTP_File_Get.txt
```

This is my code to UNZIP:

```
SET v_date=%1
if [%v_date%] == [] SET v_date=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
cd "M:\Development\Data History\"
::SET v_file="M:\Development\Data History\Filename_%v_date%.zip"
::unzip -o %v_file%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "Filename_%v_date%.zip"
```

I need to move the extracted files (6 Files) into their respective folders, Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which program are you using to unzip them?

Comment: I am currently using windows 7 OS, and the program that I may want to unzip with is 7-zip 9.20 (x64 edition). The 7z application installed localy at the following path C:\Program Files\7-Zip

Answer (score 2):

To unzip the files you can use this command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "filename.zip"
```

Comment: Thank you foxidrive! I was able to extract the file.
I would now like to move the extracted files to the respective folder locally.
There are 6 files named as File1,File2,File3,File4,...file6
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Open a new question - they are free.  SO is designed for one question and a solution,and not for ever-changing questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "source=%userprofile%\Desktop\basanta\Automation\a"
set "target=%userprofile%\Desktop\basanta\Automation\b"
FOR %%A IN ("%source%\*.gz") DO (
     "%programfiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~A" -o"%target%\%%~pA"
     del "%%~A" /Y
)
```

Use the above code by saving it to .bat file extension

Remember `%userprofile%` is for the directory, `%programfiles%` for the program files set as a variable in windows

**hope that helps**